# React native does not recognize static variable

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to use navigationOptions but reactNative doesn't recognize "static".

I've tried with classes and it worked, but with the function it didn't work

```
export default function Home() {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Home',
  };
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.h1}>Home</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined
    at DeltaPatcher.applyDelta (DeltaPatcher.js:77)
    at deltaUrlToBlobUrl (deltaUrlToBlobUrl.js:28)
    at async getBlobUrl ((index):237)
    at async WebSocket.ws.onmessage ((index):192)
```

Comment: `Home` is a function, not a class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, you can create a static variable shared by all instances like this:

```
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.h1}>Home</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

Home.navigationOptions = {
  title: 'Home',
};
```

In JavaScript functions are first-class objects. So being an object, you can assign properties to a function.

In ES6 the class keyword was introduced with an accompanied static keyword.